# Tuple with named elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, sys, namedtuple

In python 2.7.10, `sys.version_info` from the `sys` module is:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

What python type is this? It appears to be some sort of a tuple with named elements, and you can refer to either

```
sys.version_info[0]
```

or

```
sys_version_info.major
```

The type command returns

```
<type 'sys.version_info'>
```

which is somewhat unhelpful. I know it is not a named tuple, and it's not a plain tuple, but what is it? How does one construct such an item?

Comment: Please clarify - you know about collections.namedtuple already and want to know what sys.version_info is and how it differs from collections.namedtuple?

Comment: It's a [built-in type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9907203a7b805630b1fe69e770164449b5d53cff/Python/sysmodule.c#L1551), I don't think you can create custom instances of it.

Comment: I was unable to find a description of what this object is in the 2.7 documentation for sys.version_info. I was puzzled as to how a tuple could have named elements, and was asking how to make a tuple like this. Now I know it is a built-in type, is there a name for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 4):

`sys.version_info` is actually a C struct object defined in [structseq.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/structseq.c). As the comment at the top of that code indicates, it's primarily intended as an implementation tool for modules:

```C
/* Implementation helper: a struct that looks like a tuple.  See timemodule
   and posixmodule for example uses. */
```

If you want a similar Python object, this is a little bit like [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). In fact the doc string for `sys.version_info` uses "named tuple" to describe the object:

```
>>> print sys.version_info.__doc__
sys.version_info

Version information as a named tuple.
```

Alternatively, you might be able to use the structseq object directly at C level with the [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/).

Answer (score 1):

According to the sys module documentation:

> Static objects:
>
> [...]
>
> version_info -- version information as a **named tuple**
>
> [...]

Comment: I referred to 2.7 in my post. The 2.7 doc has only:

Changed in version 2.7: Added named component attributes

No mention of named tuples.